# Не могу поставить счетчик в цикл while

Tags: python, циклы

Нужно вывести кол-во итераций

Вот код: ([полностью](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5_Python))

```
def newtons_method(a, b, f, f1):
    x0 = (a + b) / 2
    x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / f1(x0))
    n = int()
    while True:
        n += 1
        if math.fabs(x1 - x0) < e:
            return x1
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / f1(x0))
    print('Кол-во итераций:', n)
```

Выделяет последнюю строку: This code is unreachable и ничего не выводит. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('Кол-во итераций:', n)
```

Не доступен потому что находится после return.

Исправить можно так

```
def newtons_method(a, b, f, f1):
    x0 = (a + b) / 2
    x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / f1(x0))
    n = int()
    while True:
        n += 1
        if math.fabs(x1 - x0) < e:
            break
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / f1(x0))
    print('Кол-во итераций:', n)
    return x1
```

Comment: только исправленный код не так должен выглядеть (return x1 важно вернуть после if, пример у Эникейщика), иначе ответ функции полностью меняется

Comment: return x1 тут выполнится после if. не вижу разницы в вычислениях. break тут прерывает цикл в том же месте

Answer (score 1):

return выходит из функции, возвращая значение х1.  Последняя строка недостижима, потому что или цикл продолжается, или функция завершается, не дойдя до той строки ( потому что она за пределами цикла).

Можно сделать так:

```
while True:
        n += 1
        if math.fabs(x1 - x0) < e:
            print('Кол-во итераций:', n)
            return x1
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x0 - (f(x0) / f1(x0))
```

Comment: смотри внимательней, там return

Comment: @eri а, ок. Не увидел.

Comment: Прошу принять другой ответ, потому что eri увидел, что в цикле есть return, а я нет.